# Convert grouped log entry to single line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have one log (generated by Unison file syncronized) thats look like this:

```
UNISON 2.51.3 (OCAML 4.11.1) started propagating changes at 15:25:10.21 on 27 Feb 2023
[BGN] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile01.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
[END] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile01.pdf
[BGN] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile02.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
[END] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile02.pdf
[BGN] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
Shortcut: copied /home/testsync/TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from local file /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx
[END] Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx
[BGN] Updating file TestFolder/01/TestFile04.jpg from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
[END] Updating file TestFolder/01/TestFile04.jpg
[BGN] Deleting /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx from /home/testsync
UNISON 2.51.3 (OCAML 4.11.1) finished propagating changes at 15:25:46.24 on 27 Feb 2023
```

And I want to get a result similar to this:

```
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile01.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile02.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Shortcut: copied /home/testsync/TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from local file /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Updating file TestFolder/01/TestFile04.jpg from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Deleting /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx from /home/testsync
```

In other words, I need to memorize the date and time showed on row `started propagating changes` and print back to all `[BGN]` and `Shortcut` rows that follows until rows `finished propagating changes`.

How I can do it in a bash script?

I have done some test using `cat`, `grep` and `awk` concatenated but I wasn't able to achieve the output I need. I need to use a Bash script because the format of log is the default log of Unison file synchronizer program but I want to have a trace of all the modification made by the synchronization and I need to do this after the program has run.

Thanks to Ed Morton for his reply that resolve my problem. I have only modified a little the awk syntax because in input log can be more than once sections (I have forget to tell this). My final AWK syntax is the following:

```
sub(/.*started propagating changes at /,"") {
    mthNr = index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$4) / 3
    ts = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02dT%s", $5, mthNr, $3, $1)
    next
}
sub(/^\[BGN] /,"") || /^Shortcut/ {
    print ts, $0
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome here. So, have you tried something so far? Why does this have to be done in a bash script?

Comment: I have done some test using cat, grep and awk concatenated but I won't able to achieve the output I need. I need to use a bash script because the format of log is the default log of Unison file syncronizer program but I want to have a trace of all the modification made by the sincronization and I need to do this after the program has run.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments, but [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737093/edit) your question instead. This way all the relevant info is readily available. I added your latest comment now to the question as-is, my edit will become visible when approved by another member of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/.*started propagating changes at /,"") {
    ts = $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $1
    next
}
sub(/^\[BGN] /,"") || /^Shortcut/ {
    print ts, $0
}
/finished propagating/ {
    exit
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile01.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile02.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Shortcut: copied /home/testsync/TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from local file /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Updating file TestFolder/01/TestFile04.jpg from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
27 Feb 2023 15:25:10.21 Deleting /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx from /home/testsync
```

Consider changing your timestamp to something sortable and generally more useful like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) though (append your time zone info as appropriate):

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/.*started propagating changes at /,"") {
    mthNr = index("  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$4) / 3
    ts = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02dT%s", $5, mthNr, $3, $1)
    next
}
sub(/^\[BGN] /,"") || /^Shortcut/ {
    print ts, $0
}
/finished propagating/ {
    exit
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile01.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile02.pdf from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Copying TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Shortcut: copied /home/testsync/TestFolder/01/TestFile03.xlsx from local file /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Updating file TestFolder/01/TestFile04.jpg from //10.0.0.2//home/testsync to /home/testsync
2023-02-27T15:25:10.21 Deleting /home/testsync/TestFolder/02/TestFile03.xlsx from /home/testsync
```